Is it halal to make memorabilia of family who passed away?
My sister passed away from a born sickness a few days ago. She had a wheel chair i would like to turn into a memorabilia of some sort. I wanted to take it to a black smith and have it smelted and shaped into something. Is this halal? My mother is having a hard time letting go because she was her whole life when she was born. I want to make this to let her know that she is ranked high in jannah.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Is your question about a "memorabilia" being halal or haram? or about whether you can do that with the wheel chair without your mother's permission?
